# Using HDMI on my Lenovo E530 Win 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, hdtv, lenovo-laptop

I just bought this Lenovo E530 and tried to get the LT to recognize my SONY TV. I unplugged the HDMI cable on the LT but still couldn't get the image on my TV. I also went to the Display setting panels and chose Mirroring. Won't work either.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

With the HDMI cable plugged into the laptop and the TV, select the appropriate source the TV i.e if you plugged th HDMI cable into HDMI 1 then select HDMI 1 using the source button on your remote, failing that does laptop detect the TV under display settings.